# The method sign.setline is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, server, bukkit

im haveing a problem running a setline command
witch i want to set the line of a sign with..
it isn't doing anything

This is the part of the code that has the setline method in it it will run with a few other things when the player will give the input (the "if (SignEvent.isNumericArray(times))" is true for sure and the code is running i did check that )

```
  if (SignEvent.isNumericArray(times)){

                double uses = Double.parseDouble(times);
                uses = uses -1;


                sign.setLine(2 , uses + "/" + str[1] + parts[1]);


                if (uses <= 0){
                sign.setLine(0, ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "StartPayment");  
                }
            }
```

i did check a few things :

- no errors in console or eclipse error list
- object sign is type Sign imported from import org.bukkit.block.Sign
- object sign is the right sign (`checked by doing  e.getPlayer().sendMessage(sign.getLine(0));` it worked..
- no matter what the string is it isn't working
- no matter where i put this line of code its not working
- the this line is running

i just have no idea what could i do to fix it i tried a lot of things and im pretty sure the problem is in the 
`sign.setLine(2 , uses + "/" + str[1] + parts[1]);` line

any one have any idea for what did i do wrong ?

Note: no matter where in this method i put the setline method or with what string/lineIndex ,it isn't doing anything

Comment: Well you haven't told us what you expect it to do, or what it actually does, which makes it very hard to help...

Comment: if it wasn't clear i expect the setline method to set the line of the sign but it isn't doing anything

Comment: Have you tried using `setLine(0, ...)` instead, given that you've checked you can *get* that line?

Comment: im sure that the if statement is true and with no errors im pretty sure the line gets executed again i did my testing . and as i said i tried a simple string like sign.setLine(0, "hey"); it isn't working and sign.getLine is working . there is also something with colors i need to overwrite in the line im trying to set ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to execute sign.update(); after a modification to apply changes.